# Monitoring a file that gets created by a sub-program executed in my in c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, fork, exec, tail

I'm executing a script from my c++ code. During its execution this script (say `my_script`) writes some information to a file (say `a.txt`) and I want to print that information in my main program's transcript.
How can I achieve this?

Initially I wasn't interested in "a.txt", and was just executing `my_script` via `system("my_script")`.

I tried using `tail -F a.txt`. Not sure if I'm doing it properly and maybe there is a better solution.
Is running `tail -F` with a detached thread a good idea at all?

```
// assume this does some job and also
// generates a.txt with below content (there can be any number of lines containing myText)
//
// header 1
// header 2
// myText someOtherText1
// myText some other text 2
void
runMyScript()
{
    system("my_script");
}

void
monitorFile(const std::string& fName, pid_t pid)
{
    std::stringstream cmdSS;
    cmdSS << "tail -q -F --pid=" << pid << " " << fName
          << " |grep myText"; // I need to print only lines containing myText
    std::string cmd(cmdSS.str());
    system(cmd.c_str());
}

// solution 1
int main() {
    pid_t parentPID = getpid();
    // just create a new empty file
    // this helps to suspend messages from tail, like below
    // tail: cannot open 'a.txt' for reading: No such file or directory
    // tail: 'a.txt' has appeared;  following new file
    std::fstream myFstream;
    myFstream.open("a.txt", std::fstream::out);
    myFstream.close();
    
    // actually would be better to stop tail when my_prog is done
    // so, I tried solution 2 as well
    std::thread t(monitorFile, "a.txt", parentPID);
    t.detach();

    runMyScript();
    
    return 0;
}

// solution 2
/*
int main() {
    std::fstream myFstream;
    myFstream.open("a.txt", std::fstream::out);
    myFstream.close();
    
    pid_t cPID = fork();
    if (cPID== 0) { // child
        execl("/bin/csh", "csh", "my_script", (char *) nullptr);
        perror("execl failed");
    } else if (cPID > 0) { // parent
        thread t(monitorFile, "a.txt", cPID);
        t.detach();

        // wait for my_script to finish
        int status;
        waitpid(cPID, &status, 0);
    } else {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
*/
```

Comment: You could use `inotify`  to get notified when the file changes etc. but wouldn't it be better to write the whole thing in _one_ language, like C++ for example?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, do you mean implementing my simplified version of "tail -F" in c++?

Comment: I mean, figure out what you want the C++ program + script to do and then settle for one programming language to make that happen. If there are complicated things done by the shell script, there are most likely libraries you can use from C++ that does the same thing.

Comment: I cannot really modify the script part (it is a wrapper over a different executable - I don't have much control over it). And I've tried to show simplified version of some portion of a larger program here.

Comment: Even if I implement my own version of "tail -F" (let's assume monitorFile does that), I would still need to start / stop it properly. I'm mainly interested what is the proper way of doing so.

Comment: Well, the whole chain of commands would be better controlled using the `boost::process` library but for your `tail` and `grep` you should be able to do it all in C++. Just monitor when the file changes with `inotify`, read the new data and do the matching you need. You can do `std::regex`es in C++ too, but to match `myText` regex is overkill and a simple `std::string::find` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look into `boost::process` library.

Comment: Please don't ever use `system()` - it's a security nightmare.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, is it the case even when I know / trust the program to be executed (it's not user controllable)?

Comment: @Somerandomprogrammer -A big part of the problem is that you can't trust *what* program is going to be executed. Consider this; the `PATH` environment variable may be modified outside the control of your program. The shell that's being used to execute the program might be changed by an attacker. The environment (variables) that your program executes in may not be entirely under your control. Separating the stdout and stderr streams from your program may be difficult. `system` is a well known function, so if you run it on a system without ASLR its address is known (and that can be exploited).

Comment: @Somerandomprogrammer And that's just the beginning. There are *many* more things wrong with `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing notify for real-time file change notifications. However, ponder the benefits of consolidating the entire codebase into a single language, such as C++. Isn't the idea of a unified language, like C++, more advantageous for seamless integration and streamlined development?